# Phaser.io JSON callback on load

Tags: javascript, json, callback, phaser-framework

I'm making a game where I store the data for units in a JSON file, units.json, which I load into the game in the `preload()` function. I also have a function called `setupUnitTextures()` which goes through a list in the JSON and loads all the units. The problem is, I get an error when calling this function because the JSON hasn't loaded yet. Here is the preload() function:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.json('units', 'units.json');
    game.load.spritesheet('archer', 'assets/archer.png', 8, 8);
    setupUnitTextures();
}
```

What I need is a way to have a callback, so when the JSON is loaded, it loads the textures by calling the `setupUnitTextures()` function. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation, which I think would also be the general recommendation for Phaser development, would be to have another state which preloads any assets needed later, that you'll then preload.

In some templates, this might mean having a **Boot** state and then a **Preloader** state. This is usually how loading bars are generated.

Alternatively, you may want to look at [Phaser's asset pack example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/loader/asset-pack) as an alternative method to loading a number of assets from a JSON file.

Comment: +1 to this approach. Use the phaser states subsystem so you can have an entire Boot state and do all the heavy load there.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onLoadComplete](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Loader.html#onLoadComplete) event:

```
game.load.onLoadComplete.add(setupUnitTextures, this);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think the problem is because I use the textures in the `create()` function. Maybe the best way to do this would be to have a loading bar. Is there a way to make a loading bar so the create() function is only called once the loading is finished?